# Texture doesn't show in web browser, exporting model from Blender using Three.js (JSON)

Tags: json, three.js

I'm having trouble loading texture, here is my code:

```
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load( "chair.json", function ( geometry ) {
            var model = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/wood.jpg' ) } ) );
            scene.add(model);
            } );
```

[here is my json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoAif.png)

Comment: As far as I can see, your model has no uv coordinates.

Comment: @Mugen87 I see, but when I was exporting I checked UVs

Comment: @Mugen87 oh I got it, there was problem with unwrapping in Blender!